# Function Arguments/Name on Radare and IDA

Tags: ida, disassembly, radare2, disassemblers, functions

I am starting with reverse engineering and Radare and I'm facing the following problem, on IDA Free I see the following code:

```
mov     ecx, 11h
lea     edi, [esp+1208h+StartupInfo]
rep stosd
lea     eax, [esp+1208h+ProcessInformation]
lea     ecx, [esp+1208h+StartupInfo]
push    eax             ; lpProcessInformation
push    ecx             ; lpStartupInfo
push    0               ; lpCurrentDirectory
push    0               ; lpEnvironment
push    8000000h        ; dwCreationFlags
push    1               ; bInheritHandles
push    0               ; lpThreadAttributes
lea     edx, [esp+1224h+CommandLine]
push    0               ; lpProcessAttributes
push    edx             ; lpCommandLine
push    0               ; lpApplicationName
mov     [esp+1230h+StartupInfo.cb], 44h ; 'D'
call    ebx ; CreateProcessA
jmp     loc_100010E9
```

However, when I use Radare I can't see the pushed arguments of the function called with ebx (on IDA I can see that it is CreateProcessA, but on Radare it is not displayed):

```
│ ╎╎│││││   0x10001179      b911000000     mov ecx, 0x11               ; 17
│ ╎╎│││││   0x1000117e      8d7c2434       lea edi, [var_44h]
│ ╎╎│││││   0x10001182      f3ab           rep stosd dword es:[edi], eax
│ ╎╎│││││   0x10001184      8d442424       lea eax, [var_54h]
│ ╎╎│││││   0x10001188      8d4c2434       lea ecx, [var_44h]
│ ╎╎│││││   0x1000118c      50             push eax
│ ╎╎│││││   0x1000118d      51             push ecx
│ ╎╎│││││   0x1000118e      6a00           push 0
│ ╎╎│││││   0x10001190      6a00           push 0
│ ╎╎│││││   0x10001192      6800000008     push 0x8000000
│ ╎╎│││││   0x10001197      6a01           push 1                      ; 1
│ ╎╎│││││   0x10001199      6a00           push 0
│ ╎╎│││││   0x1000119b      8d9424290200.  lea edx, [arg_195h]
│ ╎╎│││││   0x100011a2      6a00           push 0
│ ╎╎│││││   0x100011a4      52             push edx
│ ╎╎│││││   0x100011a5      6a00           push 0
│ ╎╎│││││   0x100011a7      c744245c4400.  mov dword [var_44h], 0x44   ; eflags
│ ╎╎│││││                                                              ; [0x44:4]=-1
│ ╎╎│││││   0x100011af      ffd3           call ebx
│ └───────< 0x100011b1      e933ffffff     jmp 0x100010e9
```

I've tried Googling it but haven't found any solution to this. Am I missing some configuration or Radare practice that would display the argument and function names?

Edit: In case anyone wants to recreate it, I am trying to analize Lab7-03.dll from Practical Malware Analysis book, which labs can be found in the github:

https://github.com/mikesiko/PracticalMalwareAnalysis-Labs

Thanks in advance! =)